# Handling 404 with Angular HTML5mode & Express?

Tags: express, angular-ui-router

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {
    root: './client/'
  });
});
```

Forwards all requests to my JS router, great. So reloading localhost:3000/foo is working. However, if my app makes an invalid request to my server, it still just sends `index.html` which makes deducing typos a bit harder than it should be.

AFAIK the only way to handle this is to explicitly define each route in Express and Angular, and anything else is a 404. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is generally to let the SPA handle the routing. So whatever request you send (that is not ajax) you will get the index page back. When the page lands with the misspelled url it will hit the 'otherwise' route and revert to `/`.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function Configurator($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

If you want to measure that or handle it then you have to use middleware in your routes.

To handle bad ajax requests you can add an 'unhandled' flag to the request object and use [middeware](http://expressjs.com/guide/writing-middleware.html) to handle it if it matches a route selector. If it does not by the time it reaches the main send block then:

```
app.route('/*')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    console.log('in', req.unhandled, req.xhr);
    if (req.unhandled && req.xhr) {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    } else {
      res.sendFile(
        app.get('appPath') + '/index.html', {
          root: config.root
        }
      );
    }
  });
```